# knockout js stuck with very simple but can't

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-2.0, knockout-mvc

I get some json objects from server but I can't get them to my view. What is that I am doing wrong.

I have a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/cy6kC/

```
 var volModel = function() {
 self.Vol = ko.observable({"ID": 1,"Name": 1});
 }
 var volunteerModel = new volModel();
 ko.applyBindings(new volunteerModel());
```

Comment: Have you tried: ko.applyBindings(volunteerModel); You're initialising the view model twice, which I wouldn't expect to work.

Comment: Your code is very strange. Your `volunteerModel` is already an object so you don't need to call it `new volunteerModel()` which is not even a valid JS syntax. And by the way your binding should be `data-bind="value: Vol().ID"`

Comment: put this as the answer. it worked. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems with your current code:

**First**

```
var volunteerModel = new volModel();
ko.applyBindings(new volunteerModel());
```

will throw an `TypeError: object is not a function` because `volunteerModel` is an object so you cannot call with with `new`. You just need to write:

```
var volunteerModel = new volModel();
ko.applyBindings(volunteerModel);
```

**Second**

Your current binding is borken

```
<input data-bind="value: Vol.ID" />
```

because `Vol` is observable (which is a function) you need the `()` if you are using it in an expression:

```
<input data-bind="value: Vol().ID" />
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CfEXJ/).

Comment: You are right nemesv. Thanks .., I think I pissed off someone and they marked this question down :(